# how to find a piece of text between <h3> and </h3> in an html page with python

Tags: python, html, python-re

There is an html page
you need to collect the text in the list, which is contained between the h3 and /h3 tags

```html
<h3 id="basics">1. Creating a Web Page</h3>
<p>

Once you've made your "home page" (index.html) you can add more pages to
your site, and your home page can link to them.

<h3 id="syntax">>2. HTML Syntax</h3>
```

i dont know how to write a pattern for this, pls help to get values "1. Creating a Web Page" and ">2. HTML Syntax"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use library like beautifulsoup for crawling webpages.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = requests.get('url to your page')
html.encoding = 'utf-8'
sp = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html5lib")

# to get all h3 in the page
list_h3 = sp.find_all('h3')
for h3 in list_h3:
    print(h3.text)
```

Comment: It is more parsing or pulling data out of HTML that is `BeautifulSoup` for but definitely recommended to use in this case.

Comment: i have got an error while running your code:
 - Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?

I have already done "pip intsall html5lib", but it doesnt work
What should i do

Comment: i wrote "html.parser" instead of "html5lib", and it works,
but one problem: it only print necessary text, but list contains element with tags
How could i get list with only necessary text?

Comment: @XazratxonSultonxonov: Please improve your question to clarify *How could i get list with only necessary text*

Comment: @XazratxonSultonxonov is this your desired output ['1. Creating a Web Page','2. HTML Syntax'] ?

Comment: @Ranjith yes, i need to get list: ['Content', '1. Creating a Web Page', '2. HTML Syntax', ...]
but now if write:
 - list_h3 = [found for found in sp.find_all('h3')]
i get list:
 - [<h3 id="contents">CONTENTS</h3>, <h3 id="basics">1. Creating a Web Page</h3>, ...]

Comment: oh, sorry, it is all ok, i write it with word "text": list_h3 = [found.text for found in sp.find_all('h3')]

Answer (score 0):

This should work by eliminating parts of the actual tags

```
html="<h3 id='basics'>1. Creating a Web Page</h3>"
text=html.replace("<h3","").split(">")[1].split("</")[0]
```

Comment: This won't work if the HTML contains any escape sequences

Comment: he didnt say there would be these are headers

Comment: No, there is no excuse for badly parsing HTML, even if it *appears* to work in *some* situation.

Comment: this works for the situation he gave us, if he explained it needed to be interchangable with other tags we could create functions to do this but in his question he did not mention it would use escape sequences.

Comment: This won't work for any other tags though. What if the attribute contains a `<>` character?

Comment: then we can just write a line that will ignore strings within the tags where attributes are defined. Just index where the string is and remove anything in between and follow same process

Comment: Your answer will fail for a lot of perfectly valid HTML. Yes you can probably use a lot more complex code to clear all the edge cases but why would you when there are plenty of high quality easy to use HTML parsers available